# Bootstrap 4 margin code mt-auto not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to make a sticky footer but mt-auto not working at all. I tried many things to solve it but nothings worked. Other margin-padding codes like mt-1 mb-2 not working too...

HTML : https://pastecode.io/s/kdS4RzFTTJ
CSS : https://pastecode.io/s/5N80x5h1YE

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #24252A;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
    color:#f7f7f7;
}
  
.navbar {
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

.navbar-collapse{
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

/* options section */

.options{
    margin-top:10rem;
    margin-bottom:2rem;
    color:#f7f7f7;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.circles-wrap{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.circle{
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.circle-text{
    margin-top:1rem;
    font-size:1.5rem;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.ss{
    margin-top:auto;
}

.circle img{
    width:150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Emir</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Local CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Emirhan Sirkeci</a>
        <button id="navbar-toggler" class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExample04" aria-controls="navbarsExample04" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
  
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarsExample04">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Github</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Me</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <section class="container options">
        <div class="circles-wrap">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="circle">
                    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
                </div>
            </a>
            <label class="circle-text">Songs</label>
        </div>

        <div class="circles-wrap">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="circle">
                    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
                </div>
            </a>
            <label class="circle-text">Movies</label>
        </div>

        <div class="circles-wrap">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="circle">
                    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
                </div>
            </a>
            <label class="circle-text">My Posts</label>
        </div>
    </section>

    <footer class="container mt-2">
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
    </footer>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="frontend.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

add this class on body `d-flex  flex-row`

```
 <footer class="container mt-auto">
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
</footer>
```

try this

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with sticky footer:

```css
/* ADDED */
    html, body{
      height: 100%;
    }
    body{
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      
    }

    body > section.container {
      flex: 1 0 auto;
    }
    body > footer{
      flex-shrink:0;
    }
```

Get more [info](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/)

DEMO - 1

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #24252A;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
    color:#f7f7f7;
}
  
.navbar {
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

.navbar-collapse{
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

/* options section */

.options{
    margin-top:10rem;
    margin-bottom:2rem;
    color:#f7f7f7;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.circles-wrap{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.circle{
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.circle-text{
    margin-top:1rem;
    font-size:1.5rem;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.ss{
    margin-top:auto;
}

.circle img{
    width:150px;
}

/* ADDED */
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}
body{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
}

body > section.container {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
body > footer{
  flex-shrink:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Emir</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Local CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Emirhan Sirkeci</a>
        <button id="navbar-toggler" class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExample04" aria-controls="navbarsExample04" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
  
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarsExample04">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Github</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Me</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <section class="container options">
        <div class="circles-wrap">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="circle">
                    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
                </div>
            </a>
            <label class="circle-text">Songs</label>
        </div>

        <div class="circles-wrap">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="circle">
                    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
                </div>
            </a>
            <label class="circle-text">Movies</label>
        </div>

        <div class="circles-wrap">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="circle">
                    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
                </div>
            </a>
            <label class="circle-text">My Posts</label>
        </div>
    </section>

    <footer class="container mt-2">
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
    </footer>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="frontend.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

DEMO - 2

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #24252A;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
    color:#f7f7f7;
}
  
.navbar {
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

.navbar-collapse{
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

/* options section */

.options{
    /*margin-top:10rem;*/
    margin-bottom:2rem;
    color:#f7f7f7;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.circles-wrap{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.circle{
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.circle-text{
    margin-top:1rem;
    font-size:1.5rem;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.ss{
    margin-top:auto;
}

.circle img{
    width:150px;
}

/* ADDED */
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}
body{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
}

body > section.container {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
body > footer{
  flex-shrink:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Emir</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Local CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Emirhan Sirkeci</a>
        <button id="navbar-toggler" class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExample04" aria-controls="navbarsExample04" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
  
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarsExample04">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Github</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Me</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <section class="container options">
        <!--<div class="circles-wrap">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="circle">
                    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
                </div>
            </a>
            <label class="circle-text">Songs</label>
        </div>

        <div class="circles-wrap">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="circle">
                    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
                </div>
            </a>
            <label class="circle-text">Movies</label>
        </div>

        <div class="circles-wrap">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="circle">
                    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
                </div>
            </a>
            <label class="circle-text">My Posts</label>
        </div>-->
    </section>

    <footer class="container mt-2">
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
    </footer>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="frontend.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the following class in your css and in HTML

`<footer class="container mt-2 sticky-footer">`

```
.sticky-footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: sticky and fixed are not the same

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.